# Redisson Tomcat Session Replication unique JSESSIONID

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster, redisson

I am using redisson to replicate tomcat sessions of my spring application across 3 tomcat pods running tomcat v8.5. I have also deployed Redis in the same Kubernetes cluster.
Here is my tomcat context.xml config

```
<Manager className="org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager" configPath="${catalina.base}/conf/redisson.yaml" readMode="REDIS" updateMode="DEFAULT" />
```

My redisson config is as follows:

```
masterSlaveServersConfig:
  password: 'password'
  readMode: "MASTER_SLAVE"
  subscriptionMode: "SLAVE"
  slaveAddresses:
  - "redis://redis-replicas:6379"
  masterAddress: "redis://redis-master:6379"
```

When i run my application and load balance requests across all pods it creates a new JSESSIONID cookie for each request sent to different pod

This should validate JSESSIONID created on pod 1 on pod2 without creating a new one
Can anyone tell me what configuration make sure that JSESSIONID remain same across all pods for a single session ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `broadcastSessionEvents = true` setting for RedissonSessionManager.